Create Sales order in Netsuite with custom address in line item
I am trying to create a sales order in Netsuite with a single line item. I have enabled
isMultiShipTo field so that I can enter an address in the line items. I can add addresses which are in the customer address book using the following POST request
{
    "recordtype": "salesorder",
    "entity": {
        "id": "3034"
    },
    "email": "steven@xyz.com",
    "customForm": "265",
    "tranDate": "2020-6-15",
    "otherrefnum": "2188223111210f3f73888112223",
    "custbody_abm_order_type": "2",
    "memo": "This is a test memo!",
    "custbodytpw_assigned_carrier_name_serv": "test",
    "custbodytpw_resource_carrier_label": "test",
    "custbodytpw_tracking_number": "test",
    "location": {
        "id": 1
    },
    "status": {
        "id": "B",
        "refName": "Pending Fulfillment"
    },
    "ismultishipto": true,
    "item": {
        "items": [
            {
                "item": {
                    "id": 1426
                },
                "quantity": 1,
                "Description": "Test Item",
                "shipAddress": {
                    "id": "13007"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

The shipAddress 13007 is part of the addressbook of the customer. However, I want to provide a custom address in the line item which isn't in the customer's address book. I can add a custom address through the UI and as part of Netsuite documentation that custom address remains on the transaction record not the customer record but I can't do that through the API. Has anyone created it through the API?
https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/APIs/REST_API_Browser/record/v1/2024.1/index.html#/definitions/salesOrder
